# Arduino keeps executing setup

Tags: arduino, installation, arduino-uno

I've written this code recently to do an Arduino sensor station with an **Arduino UNO**. I need to recover some data from hives so that later someone can analyse them. Basically, the program reads the sensors and then stores the readings in a SD card.

I have an issue with that code. I don't know and didn't found how to solve it. The code executes itself normally but it keeps executing the setup like the loop function. So the serial outputs "setup done" and then the arduino seems to reboot and so on.

I've seen that maybe it's because my arduino hasn't enough RAM. The IDE says that it is 67% used and the program stockage is used at 70% and I also tried to plug the arduino to a 12V power supply but it didn't work too.

Thanks for your answers.

(Some variables may be in french because I speak french and I probably left english mistakes) :)

```
/*
  SD card datalogger

 This example shows how to log data from three analog sensors
 to an SD card using the SD library.

 The circuit:
 * analog sensors on analog ins 0, 1, and 2
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4 (for MKRZero SD: SDCARD_SS_PIN)

 created  24 Nov 2010
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include <SD.h>
#include <Adafruit_MPL3115A2.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <OneWire.h>


#define DHTPIN 2  
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 3
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
RTC_DS1307 rtc;
Adafruit_MPL3115A2 baro = Adafruit_MPL3115A2();

const int chipSelect = 10;
float temperatureWP;
float temperature2;
int luminosite;
float humidity;
float pascals;
float heatIndex;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  dht.begin();
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");

  }


    // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled

    // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
    // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
     //rtc.adjust(DateTime(2018, 3, 11, 14, 19, 0));


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog12.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  dataFile.println("Date et heure \t pression \t luminosite \t temperatureWP \t temperature2 \t humidity \t heat index");
  dataFile.close();
  Serial.println("Date et heure \t pression \t luminosite \t temperatureWP \t temperature2 \t humidity \t heat index");

  Serial.println("SETUP DONE");

}

void loop() {

  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  // make a string for assembling the data to log:
  String dataString = "";
    sensors.requestTemperatures();

  // read three sensors and append to the string:
    temperatureWP = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

    temperature2 = dht.readTemperature();

    humidity = dht.readHumidity();

    luminosite = analogRead(A1);

    pascals = baro.getPressure();

    heatIndex = dht.computeHeatIndex(temperature2, humidity, false);

    dataString += String(pascals);
    dataString += String("\t");
    dataString += String(luminosite);
    dataString += String("\t");
    dataString += String(temperatureWP);
    dataString += String("\t");
    dataString += String(temperature2);
    dataString += String("\t");
    dataString += String(humidity);
    dataString += String("\t");
    dataString += String(heatIndex);
  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file is available, write to it:
  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.print(now.day(), DEC);
    dataFile.print('/');
    dataFile.print(now.month(), DEC);
    dataFile.print('/');
    dataFile.print(now.year(), DEC);
    dataFile.print(" ");
    dataFile.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    dataFile.print(':');
    dataFile.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    dataFile.print(':');
    dataFile.print(now.second(), DEC);
    dataFile.print("\t");
    dataFile.println(dataString);
    dataFile.close();
    // print to the serial port too:

    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(dataString);

  }
  // if the file isn't open, pop up an error:
  else {
    Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");



  }
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: You are probably right that the Arduino reboots regularly. Now I think it is one of the sensor reading that causes problem. First you should add some prints between the reads to know exactly which line causes problem. Also note that 99% flash usage is not a problem, but if you are to high in RAM, then you might have problems. What is not taken into account by compiler in your 67% RAM usage is the stack (each function call adds some bytes on stack) and the heap (dynamic variable allocation). It's always difficult to estimate what is "too much" stack usage.

Comment: There's something in `setup` or in `loop` that crashes and makes the arduino reset himself again and again. Perhaps try to add Serial prints all over the place and read which one is the last one to get executed. Note however, that Serial prints are adding an overhead to the runtime: larger stack, less RAM memory... so it could be that the act of debugging itself causes a different bug. However, it's easy to try and very often helps.

Answer (score 1):

My grain of salt here. There's something in your functions that causes a crash and makes the Arduino restart, again and again. So we need to find where this crash happens.

Without debugging it's hard to guess it, but here's my suspicion. You get to print Setup Done, so setup finished correctly. Then in loop you fail before printing anything. So there's two places: either one of the reads is making it crash, or the multiple string concatenations. I'm suspicious of the second, let me try to explain why.

Reading the implementation of `String` in the Arduino codebase, here's what happens. On every line, you do `dataString += String(something);` This is, construct a string out of *something*, calling a new allocation of a buffer using `dtostrf`, then call the `+=` operator, which calls `concat` on `dataString` taking `String(something)` as a parameter. This basically does a concat on the underlying pointer to the char array and the length, which reallocates the buffer: [read this](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1gafd300bad8b4dd2e88b07d464d76c92aa.html). And then you're essentially reallocating again and again, not knowing if this is extending the original buffer or making new ones, possibly fragmenting the heap in a nasty way, when you're running out of RAM... Sounds like it can crash :)

Solutions, well, I have no idea if your compiler has noticed the optimizations, but first of all you can get rid of the spurious construction, the operator `+=` is defined for all numeric values as well. Then, you can have your own static buffer where you go concatenate your results. Something like

```
char myBuffer[20];
dtostrf(pascals, 4, 2, *myBuffer[0]);
myBuffer[7] = '\t';
dtostrf(luminosite, 4, 2, *myBuffer[8]);
myBuffer[15] = '\t';
...
dataString += myBuffer;
```

Check the indexes by the way, this is the very much type-unsafe pointer-hell of C that C++ wanted to avoid at the cost of certain overhead, overhead that you may not have resources to pay in this circumstances.

This doesn't solve anyway the problem that your `dataString` is still being allocated and deallocated again and again every time you enter the loop. This should be a deterministic allocation, but I have no way to ensure you it would be, and then you could run into heap fragmentations, don't know.

Comment: So, I have written another program that makes the same and obviously is almost written the same and it works but thanks for your help. (I didn't understand that much because I'm a begginer).

Comment: This solution is correct. I ran into this problem myself right now, because I swapped array declarations out for `calloc` calls, which need to get `free`'d manually afterwards. This is just a reminder if anyone else runs into this problem, that there may be a memory leak somewhere in your program :)